# Sentence Structure “They are+number+objects”

Tags: sentence-structure

- They are three apples.
- Guess who is John.

For these 2 sentences, is it correct and natural to say this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They are three apples.

Here, it would be more natural to say, "There are three apples" (describing them) or "Here are three apples" (pointing at them). I can't really think of many scenarios where saying "They are three apples" would be the best choice of words.

> Guess who is John.

This one seems alright. If you had a bunch of people lined up and told me, "Guess who is John," I would understand you. It just seems a little weird out of context.

Comment: There is a picture of several people. And the title is “Listen to the conversation and guess who is John.”

Comment: Yes, that seems completely normal and is the way I would phrase it.

Comment: By the way, in your question, you wrote, "is it correct and natural to say this way?" This should be, "is it correct and natural to say IT this way?". Just a tiny correction.

Comment: Is it correct to say “Guess who John is.”?

Comment: Yes, that also seems right, as well as "Guess which one is John," et cetera. Although "Guess who is John" definitely doesn't sound right.

Comment: Do you mean that “Guess who John is.” and “Guess which one John is.” are grammatically correct while “Guess who/which one is John.” not?

Comment: Yes, although some people might say, "Guess who's John"/"Guess which one is John." It might just come down to preference.

Comment: -What are these? -They are apples. These are sentences from a textbook. When a numeral is added before “apples”, does it sound correct to you?

Comment: Ah, yes, I hadn't thought of that. There, you could say, "They are apples" or "These are apples." The first one rolls off the tongue a bit more easily.  "They're three apples" with the numeral sounds too oddly specific; I would usually just drop it unless the person whom I'm speaking to can't see the apples.

Answer (score 0):

"They are three apples" is grammatical, but it would be a rare situation where the locution would sound natural.

"They are apples" would be a natural answer to the question, "What kind of fruit is that?"

"There are ten apples in this bag" would be a natural answer to the question "How many apples are in that bag?"

A situation where a statement of the form you are discussing might be natural is this. You and a friend see four women seated at a table, and the friend says "Do you know those women who look so amazingly similar." You respond, "Yes, I know them. They are three sisters and a cousin so their similarity is not that amazing."

To sum up, the structure of "they are three apples" is perfectly grammatical, but it is a structure rarely used.